# Saving a new disconnected entity with an existing nested entity without duplicating the existing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is my model:

```
public class Place
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddressLine> AddressLines { get; set; }
}
public class AddressLine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Place Place { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddressLineType> AddressLineTypes { get; set; }  
}
public class AddressLineType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddressLine> AddressLines { get; set; }

}
```

When creating a new `Place` entity with EF6 I have to use a dettached entity, there is no way around it that I can see by passing a reference to the context.

My problem with this is that the `Place` and `AddressLine` are new, but the `AddressLineType` already exists.

When I try to save the `Place` entity, even though the `AddressLineType` ID property is set, because it is detached, EF will insert it as new and thusly duplicate the existing `AddressLineType` entries.

I have done some research to try and get around it and found an article that suggests the best way would be to add the `AddressLineType` as null and set the foreign key property and this will give the desired behaviour. The example was a one to many relationship but I can't see how to do that for the many to many relationship here.

I am just using naming conventions for entity frameowrk to understand mapping (I don't really touch databases much).  When I do a one to many relationship I can see it adds a foreign key automatically but how does this work in a many to many relationship?

Ideally I would like this problem to be sorted in the code that creates the `Place` but I tried doing the below in the saving code.  It doesn't add duplicate data but it throws an exception because the `AddressLineTypes` already exist.

```
foreach( var v in place.AddressLines)
{
    foreach (var v2 in v.AddressLineTypes)
    {
        db.AddressLineTypes.Attach(v2);
    }

}
```

How do I show the relationship in the disconnected entity before I add it to context and save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the state manually for disconnected entity for updating the record like this-

```
    foreach( var v in place.AddressLines)
    {
        foreach (var v2 in v.AddressLineTypes)
        {
            db.Entry<AddressLineTypes>(v2).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: I am not updatig, I am adding a new entity but that entity has nested entities that already exist and are not being updated, I just want to show the relationship.  When I set the entity state to `Unchanged` for the existing nested entity then I get the error that the primary key already exists

Comment: I think for nested entities either you need to set the state to modified or if you want them unchanged then you can also set them to null before adding main entity to the dbcontext.

Answer (score 0):

> if the entity being added has references to other entities that are
>   not yet tracked then these new entities will also be added to the
>   context and will be inserted into the database the next time that
>   SaveChanges is called.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: I have tried attaching them and setting their state to `Unchanged` but this then causes error that primary key already exists.

Comment: you have to first select records from db and than attach to th perticular entity, it will work